# Scheduling in multi-core system when one of the processor is stuck in deadlock in interrupt context

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, multicore, job-scheduling, bsd

I am using BSD Unix, but I request attention of Linux enthusiasts as well on this.

While working on a production problem, this question occurred to me, because one of the processor was stuck in a very long and time consuming interrupt context (due to programming error).

**Assumption is watch-dog timer that detects the deadlock in kernel, is disabled.**

The question is in pieces.

**1. How does preemption (enabling/disabling) works in general in multi-processing systems?**

**2. In general does each processor uses an independent clock for time sharing?**

**3. What OS scheduling policies may come into play, if one of the processor gets itself into deadlock in interrupt context?**

For 1. I know that we have APIs that help in enabling/disabling of interrupts - My question is more on its per processor usage.

For 2. I assumed, that there is only ONE clock that guides instruction scheduling for all processors.

For 3. I think that, all unbound lwps/threads can be migrated to free processors. If correct, how is this achieved?